# What is the effect of including additional representations in the action of a lattice gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model

I'm reading *Introduction to Quantum Fields on a Lattice* by Jan Smit. When introducing the lattice gauge-field action as a sum over plaquettes, Smit says that in general the action should include a sum over representations. He states that the 'Wilson action' includes only the fundamental representation, which takes the form

$$S(U) = \frac{1}{g^2\rho}\sum_{p} \text{Re}\, \left[\text{Tr} \ \{U_p\}\right],$$

whereas in general, for representations denoted by $r$, we could have a lattice action

$$S(U) = \sum_p \sum_r \beta_r \frac{\text{Re}\left[ \chi_r(U_p)\right]}{\chi_r(1)}, $$

where

$$\chi_r(U) = \text{Tr}\{{D^r(U)}\},$$

$$\frac{1}{g^2} = \sum_r \frac{\beta_r \rho_r}{d_r},\qquad d_r = \chi_r(1)$$

Unfortunately, Smit doesn't explain *why* one would generalize the action like this. Why all this focus on the representation? What does it mean physically for the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that, instead of $Tr[U_p]$, you could use any function $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ which is invariant under conjugation $f(U) \mapsto f(gUg^{-1})$, as this condition is enough to guarantee invariance under gauge transformation.  Such invariant functions are called "class functions".

One variation on the [Peter-Weyl Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) states that

> The characters of the irreducible representations of G form an orthonormal basis for the space of square-integrable class functions on G.

In other words, any class function can be written as a sum of characters, so it's enough to consider the actions you've written.

Comment: Ah okay, I hadn't been aware of that theorem. Thanks! How does one go about choosing which class function to use then? Is the Wilson action a good model for QCD, or do more general functions capture more interesting phenomena?

Comment: The Wilson action is fine for QCD.  If you run the renormalization group flow for a little ways, your  action will be mutated to some more general class function, I suppose, but I don't know of specific uses.  Usually, when you see an author considering more general actions, they're considering more general plaquettes (e.g., length 2 and height 1), with the aim of speeding up convergence.

Comment: @user1504 for instance: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.2853  sorry it's not arxiv